# JMeter can't open JMeter file with plugins

Tags: jmeter

I have an error when I try to open my saved jmx (my backup is a week old),

I tried to follow similar issues but can't load it also with JMeter 3.1,

I install new JMeter 3.2 and installed plugins with all available plugins but still get an error:

```
2017-08-30 10:03:53,394 WARN o.a.j.g.a.Load: Unexpected error. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'C:\Users\User\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\test.jmx', missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/ResultCollector
line number         : 169
version             : 3.2 r1790748
-------------------------------
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'C:\Users\User\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\test.jmx', missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/ResultCollector
line number         : 169
version             : 3.2 r1790748
-------------------------------
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:457) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.loadTree(SaveService.java:425) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:130) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doActionAfterCheck(Load.java:89) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:45) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:74) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:59) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/ResultCollector
line number         : 169
version             : 3.2 r1790748
-------------------------------
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.createConversionException(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:103) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:97) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1230) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1214) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1085) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:442) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    ... 21 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : java.lang.ClassCastException
cause-message       : org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/ResultCollector
line number         : 169
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:95) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1230) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1214) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1085) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:442) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector cannot be cast to org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:73) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:95) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1230) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1214) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1085) ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:442) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the plugins are compatible with JMeter 3.2.

Try opening your plan with the version it was created in and check you are not using deprecated elements that get removed in N+1 version.

To know about deprecated Test Elements, look at:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

Answer (score 1):

Moving to the latest Jmeter version 5.1.1 did the trick for me.

Comment: Correct. I installed jmeter using 'apt install' utility on Ubuntu, which installs old version of jmeter. In my case this old version was 2.x while the new version is 5.x. Downloaded and installed the new version and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are using latest Jmeter software.

Currently in latest version of Jmeter (3.2) if your jmx file using any kind of plugin and your Jmeter not install that plugin it will show your.

Comment: latest version is 3.3 (and about to be 4)

Answer (score 0):

Check you might have update the Your Java to java 11, please downgrade to Java8 and try running it, at current this is the only solution wht i feel.

Comment: Exception is with Java8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).