# jmeter missing.class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException

Tags: jmeter

I was running my script and it hanged and I had to force close.
Now this error appears:

[image: 1]

Comment: Similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954153/jmeter-cant-open-jmeter-file-with-plugins

Answer (score 33):

- Download "Plugins-manager.jar" from
  https://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/
- Put downloaded .jar into JMETER_INSTALLED_DIRECTORY/lib/ext directory
- Restart jmeter.

Open the script, it will show a download missing component dialog. Download missing component.

Hope this will help

Comment: Upgrade plugin manager if already installed from Run>Plugin Manager>Upgrades.

Answer (score 9):

It is indeed an error related to you missing the JMeter plugins. Since i am new to programming, I thought it might be useful i offer a more detailed guide on JMeter installation on Mac.

*Prerequisites:*

- You have Java installed - i work with Java 8 version thus if you have an older or a newer version it might not work. 
  You can check your version with ~ java -version. 
  Here you can download the jdk 8: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html.
- You have brew installed. To install it run /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)”, go to https://brew.sh/ for more info.

*How to do it*

1. Let’s first download the JMeter (version 4.0) from https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi.  You can find the zip files in the first section under **Binaries** - apache-jmeter-4.0.zip.
   Alternatively, run brew install jmeter.
2. Then move it from Downloads to your root directory: (just for simplicity, you can put it anywhere you wish.

[install apache-jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHoFm.png)

3. Go inside that folder and it’s **bin** like this: ~ cd apache-jmeter-4.0/bin
4. From there run **./jmeter.sh**

---

In JMeter you try to open the desired file but get the 'missing.class..' **error**:

[missing.class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK4PK.png)

*Installing the JMeter plugins*

1. Go to https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/ and download the Plugins Manager JAR file.
2. Following the instructions: 'put the file into lib/ext directory' translates to you going to your apache-jmeter-4.0 folder (see the first screen shot) and place the file there inside lib/ext folder.
3. restart JMeter and you can see the Plugins Manager in JMeter *Options*.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download plugins-manager.jar from https://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/
2. Put plugins-manager.jar into jmeter/lib/ext
3. Restart jmeter
4. Open script, it will ask to download dependencies, press yes
5. Go to Plugin Manager and install all the required jar dependency
6. Re-start the application

Answer (score 1):

I installed Jmeter on Ubuntu Linux using '**apt-get install jmeter**', which it seems installs a very old version of Jmeter. 
Old version => 2.x 
I downloaded the latest version using curl and installed it and the problem disappeared. 
New version => 5.x.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to lower version JMeter.
Try with installing Apache Jmeter 3.3 and install python with enable "Add python.exe to Path  http://www.python.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

i know it is late to respond to this query but it may help others who might face this issue in future.
For me, Moving to the latest Jmeter version 5.1.1 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue because i downloaded jmeter from

> sudo apt install jmeter

and it installed the jmeter of version 2.X.X. Which i guess doesn't support anything now a days. I uninstalled the jmeter from command:

> sudo apt purge jmeter

And installed the latest jmeter from http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi?Preferred=https%3A%2F%2Fdownloads.apache.org%2F After that in bin folder as i'm using ubuntu Os i used command

> sh jmeter.sh

Jmeter worked fine!!!