# Not able to open script .jmx file in jmeter,error while loading script in jmeter missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.conversionexception

Tags: jmeter

error while loading script in jmeter missing class

> com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.conversionexception

I have tried the **plugin manager**, also tried increasing the heap size still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

First need to [download](https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/):
**`"Plugins-manager.jar".`** or from [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)

*Then after this:* 
place/move it from downloads to your root directory(put the file into lib/ext directory)

Final step: Restart `jmeter`.

for more reference check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52346362/11041731) too.