# Cannot open Jmeter file in Jmeter 3.3

Tags: jmeter

I recently updated Jmeter 3.3 and I am unable to open the old file.
Can you please help? 
[image]

Comment: Can you add the error log?

Answer (score 1):

Install the required (which have you used in your test scripts) plugins from plugin manager for JMeter 3.3. This error is showing because of your missing plugins in version 3.3.

Or you can download the required plugins and put it in your /lib directory and then again restart your JMeter 3.3 again.

Comment: I haven't used any plug ins in this one.

Comment: Try to open your JMX file in XML editor and observe the line number 126. Maybe you have to add or delete necessary tags there. Please also check the JMeter error log. Maybe you had a crash during a save. You can get it back manually after adding or deleting the necessary tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to this:

[JMeter can't open JMeter file with plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954153/jmeter-cant-open-jmeter-file-with-plugins)

Opening your plan (.jmx file) to higher version of JMeter, especially created using the lower version, is not always guaranteed to be error free, based on my experience.

Try to open your plan to the version of JMeter it was created and check if you are using deprecated elements that get removed in the version you are having trouble with.

Here's the link that might help you to determine the deprecated elements on the version that you are using: http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

I Hope it helps.